# Is this usage of "whose" correct?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, pronouns

Is the following phrase (grammatically) correct?

> Bill Gates, whose company is very rich, is famous.

<sup>(I couldn't come up with a better context-free sample)</sup>

Comment: In this example, and some similar usages, it can be restructured as `Bill Gates is famous because his company is very rich`.  That's not what I'm asking for.

Comment: I'm sorry, @SLaks, but I would try to desist from creating tags such as `whose` in the future. Already, several pertinent ones exist: `adjectives`, `pronouns`, `usage`, `grammar`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

The repetition of "is" is a bit ugly but not ungrammatical.

Comment: So it's the correct version of `whose`?

Comment: @SLaks:  Yes.  'Whose' refers to the owner of the object.  'Who's' is a contraction of 'who is'.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't even see the second "*is*" as a problem. In my mind, the jump to the subsentence using commas is very orthogonal to the rest of the text. The "*whose*" is correctly used but if you're free to rephrase, you might consider the following, too.

> Bill Gates, the company of whom is very rich, is famous.

It's a bit unusual to hear that (at least amongst people I talk to) but I love the clarity of what's pointing to what. As this, a bit digressive, example.

> The motorbike, the anti-theft system of which is unbreakable, was badly damaged.

It's a true story, too, as of two weeks ago. Poor bike, the owner of which is me, is at the shop now.

:)